# Virtual environment (venv) gives a different python version from interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

In VS Code (Windows), my python interpreter points to version 3.11.
`python -V` in terminal gives me Python 3.11.0

I create a virtual environment with `python3 -m venv virtual` called virtual, and activate it with `.\virtual\Scripts\activate`.
Now in my environment, checking `python -V` gives me Python 3.9.13 instead.

How do I get venv to create a Python 3.11 environment?

Comment: You are checking your "global" installation with `python -V`, but creating the virtual environment with `python3 -m ...`. Are `python` and `python3` the same thing?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: @chepner I deleted that virtual environment and created another with `python -m venv virtual` and its `python -V` is now 3.11! Thanks for pointing that out. On a related note, how do I get my `python3` to point to my latest python version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating virtual environment with `python3` but checking version with just `python`. I want you to check if `python` and `python3` are pointing **same python executable file** before creating virtual environment.

May be try creating virtual environment using just `python`, since its version is 3.11.0.

```
$ python -m venv virtual
```

Or you can create virtual environment with specifing the path of your python 3.11 executable file.

```
$ C:/path/to/your/python3-11-execuatable/python.exe -m venv virtual
```

Comment: Yes it seems python3 and python are pointing to two different python executable files... how do I change the exec file that python3 points to?

Comment: if just python is 3.11 then create venv using first command, and let me know if it works

Comment: Yes using `python -m venv virtual` works. But a related qn - python3 is still not pointing to the latest python version. How do I fix that?

Comment: i think for window's the standard executable is python.exe. may be the older version got python3.exe in the installed directory. python or python3 are just name of executable file. if you go to the installed directory and change the name of python.exe to something like viper.exe it still gonna work. But make sure the installed directory path is added in window's environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the **view tab** above click on **Comand palette**> **python interpreter** from there you can select python 3.11, otherwise you can add it by clicking on **enter interpreter path** and then select the path where python 3.11 is located at

Comment: As I mentioned in my question above, my interpreter is already pointing to 3.11 so this doesn't solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple Solution.

Step-1: Just go to google and download python 3.11.0 and install it, don't worry if you have an upgraded version,  it will installed separately.

Step-2: Go to vs code and change your interpreter to 3.11.0, in my case,

[Check out my interpretors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rinBQ.png)

Step-3: Close the vs code and Restart your Laptop and open terminal and check version of python it will be 3.11.0 then simply install tensorflow as pip install tensorflow.

And you will get the Supported version of Tensorflow.